# AR9485 - Kubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS) wireless not connecting anymore

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, kubuntu, network-manager

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on a Asus PU301LA RO039G. Wireless and wired connection worked fine until yesterday, when the "I don't know what" happened.
Symptom is the unability to connect to my home WPA2 password protected wireless network (ASUS RT-N14U router wireless n300). Network is detected but, clicking to connect, it remains stucked to "Waiting for authorization" stage, prompting a password request continuously. The other wireless devices just connect fine. The wired connection works fine.
I tried to disable kwallet, to remove kwallet and network manager configuration files, without improvement. I tried both network-manager and wicd with same result (like the password was incorrect). I noticed in dmesg some "country code" messing up between authentication and deauthentication time.

```
[20362.252210] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[20362.259767] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[20362.259772] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[20362.259776] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20362.259779] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20362.259782] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20362.259785] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20362.259788] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20375.072612] wlan0: authenticate with bc:ee:7b:e4:0a:44
[20375.096073] wlan0: send auth to bc:ee:7b:e4:0a:44 (try 1/3)
[20375.097662] wlan0: authenticated
[20375.099932] wlan0: associate with bc:ee:7b:e4:0a:44 (try 1/3)
[20375.104054] wlan0: RX AssocResp from bc:ee:7b:e4:0a:44 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[20375.104091] wlan0: associated
[20375.104141] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[20375.106124] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[20375.106126] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[20375.106127] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[20375.106128] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[20375.106130] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[20375.106130] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[20375.106132] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[20375.106145] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[20375.106146] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[20375.106147] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[20375.106149] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[20375.106149] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[20375.106150] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm)
[20375.106151] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[20380.582768] wlan0: deauthenticating from bc:ee:7b:e4:0a:44 by local choice (reason=3)
```

The driver in use is:

```
riotste@riotste-PU301LA:~$ ls /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/driver/module/drivers/
pci:ath9k  platform:ath9k
```

I don't know what other system information outputs to post, but if someone can help I will grab any further useful informations later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please run the script and post the file from the router you are having trouble connecting too. Please add all script information to your question and delete it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Hi, some recent updating: some days ago suddenly the laptop started to connect also to home router, after kwallet password request and a period of time in which the wireless card seems to grab no wifi signals. So, for now, the problem is solved by itself (although the behavior is barely weird). So, let me know if I have to delete the whole question or add script information anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo modprobe -rv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k nohwcrypt=1
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

the settings will be lost after you reboot, so if it helps we will need to make it permanent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wild Man, but the procedure had no effect. I also tried to reset the modem and the router, but nothing changed.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in the answer but I've been in Italy for a while. I noticed no problem with the wireless network at my parents home, connection was just automatic and always fine (router TP-LINK, I don't remember the model but if you think it is useful I can ask). I also noticed no problem with the wireless router in my workplace (Serbia, where I am now). Moreover, yesterday I tried to reset the home cable modem to which the wifi router is attached and after setting back up wifi infos, the laptop connected. I will post wireless_script output from here and, if you need, also from home.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless infos - workplace (wireless working)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 14 Aug 2014 12:36 CEST +0200

Script from: 04 Aug 2014 18:47 UTC +0000

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:12 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop #####

KDE Plasma Workspace

##### lspci #####

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2126]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

##### lsusb #####

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0010 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 13d3:3402 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #####

asus_nb_wmi            16862  0 
asus_wmi               23495  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13708  1 asus_wmi
ath9k                 144602  0 
ath9k_common           13359  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              438205  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    23922  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              546051  1 ath9k
ath3k                  13110  0 
bluetooth             342206  23 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
cfg80211              409394  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
wmi                    18673  1 asus_wmi
video                  18903  2 i915,asus_wmi

##### interfaces #####

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig #####

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC addr eth0>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC addr wlan0>  
          inet addr:192.168.41.169  Bcast:192.168.41.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e71:d9ff:fed3:39e3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:88111 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42495 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:69882805 (69.8 MB)  TX bytes:6544339 (6.5 MB)

##### iwconfig #####

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"BS4U-WiFi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC addr mladeks>   
          Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:11  Invalid misc:271   Missed beacon:0

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.41.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.41.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.2.2

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [BS4U-WiFi] ---------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC addr wlan0>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           39 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    VladanBilja:     Infra, <MAC addr VladanBilja>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 55 WPA
    Appricot:        Infra, <MAC addr Appricot>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA WPA2
    eltingslobo:     Infra, <MAC addr eltingslobo>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WPA WPA2
    Appricot:        Infra, <MAC addr Appricot>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WPA WPA2
    HP-Print-10-Officejet Pro 8600: Infra, <MAC addr BS4U-WiFi>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37
    *BS4U-WiFi:      Infra, <MAC addr mladeks>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA WPA2
    mladeks:         Infra, <MAC addr FAMILYSPORT>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA
    Fondacija Djokovic: Infra, <MAC addr Shmul>, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 55 WPA WPA2
    FAMILYSPORT:     Infra, <MAC addr SoFaBG>, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 69 WPA WPA2
    Shmul:           Infra, <MAC addr TP-LINK_4346B0>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 25 WPA2
    HOLD Milos:      Infra, <MAC addr AFBG-WiFi01>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    SoFaBG:          Infra, <MAC addr kika>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2
    TP-LINK_4346B0:  Infra, <MAC addr Vranjes>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA WPA2
    AFBG-WiFi01:     Infra, <MAC addr Civerson>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA
    kika:            Infra, <MAC addr adsl.moskva>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 25 WEP
    Vranjes:         Infra, <MAC addr zora>, Freq 2447 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA2
    Civerson:        Infra, <MAC address>, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA WPA2
    adsl.moskva:     Infra, <MAC address>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 55 WPA
    zora:            Infra, <MAC address>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 79 WPA

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.41.169
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.41.1

    DNS:             8.8.8.8
    DNS:             8.8.2.2

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC addr eth0>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=false
WimaxEnabled=true
WiMAXEnabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels #####

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Current Frequency=2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #####

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC addr mladeks>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"BS4U-WiFi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000000820779cb
                    Extra: Last beacon: 200ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC addr eltingslobo>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"eltingslobo"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000012a4f59bf
                    Extra: Last beacon: 27188ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC addr Shmul>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Fondacija Djokovic"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000007d23c3f1e3
                    Extra: Last beacon: 27188ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC addr TP-LINK_4346B0>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Shmul"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000051fcf70168
                    Extra: Last beacon: 532ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC addr Appricot>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Appricot"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000024777a3227
                    Extra: Last beacon: 120ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC addr BS4U-WiFi>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"HP-Print-10-Officejet Pro 8600"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000002ab0b72a9
                    Extra: Last beacon: 116ms ago
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC addr Appricot>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Appricot"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000027126cc895
                    Extra: Last beacon: 192ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 08 - Address: <MAC addr VladanBilja>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"VladanBilja"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000038b09ab014
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1616ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 09 - Address: <MAC addr SoFaBG>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FAMILYSPORT"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000ad0abcbb233
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1980ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 10 - Address: <MAC addr Civerson>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"AFBG-WiFi01"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000ad094d9a3d0
                    Extra: Last beacon: 27188ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 11 - Address: <MAC addr AFBG-WiFi01>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"HOLD Milos"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000012e7736a171
                    Extra: Last beacon: 504ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 12 - Address: <MAC address>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"zora"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000acf963ec714
                    Extra: Last beacon: 272ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 13 - Address: <MAC address>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"adsl.moskva"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001df0e53d6b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2800ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

Answer (score 0):

```
##### module infos #####

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     7EAAD420ADF6B9354F0C8C1
alias:          platform:qca955x_wmac
alias:          platform:ar934x_wmac
alias:          platform:ar933x_wmac
alias:          platform:ath9k
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002810bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Fsd00007202bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002130bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000612bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000652bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000642bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd0000302Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001028sd0000020Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000103Csd0000217Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000103Csd000018E3bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000017AAsd00003026bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000213Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000662bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000672bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000622bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd00003028bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E069bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd0000302Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003026bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002812bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002811bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00006671bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000632bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd0000A119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E068bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002176bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003028bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000037sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000010CFsd00001783bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000014CDsd00000064bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000014CDsd00000063bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv0000103Csd00001864bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006641bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006631bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001043sd0000850Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001A3Bsd00002110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001969sd00000091bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000017AAsd00003214bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv0000168Csd00003117bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006661bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001A3Bsd00002116bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000033sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001043sd0000850Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00001C01bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00001C00bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001F95bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001195bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001F86bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001186bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00002001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00002000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Fsd00007197bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E04Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E04Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000011ADsd00006628bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000011ADsd00006627bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001C56sd00004001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002100bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002C97bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000017AAsd00003219bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000017AAsd00003218bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C708bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C680bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C706bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd00004106bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd00004105bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000185Fsd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000185Fsd00003119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000168Csd00003122bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000168Csd00003119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E075bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002152bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd0000126Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002126bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001237bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002086bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv00001A3Bsd00002C37bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd00001536bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd0000147Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd0000147Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv0000185Fsd0000309Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv00001A32sd00000306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000011ADsd00006642bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000011ADsd00006632bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv0000105Bsd0000E01Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv00001A3Bsd00001C71bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000029sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000027sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000024sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000023sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     696B00A6C59713EC0966997
depends:        ath,ath9k_hw
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     4809F3842A0542CD6B556D3
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     88A67C5359B02C5A710AFCF
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     98A5245588C09E5E41690D0
alias:          usb:v0489pE036d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0489pE03Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0489pE02Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3pE003d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p3121d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3402d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04C5p1330d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0489pE04Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0489pE056d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0489pE04Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3393d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0489pE057d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0930p0220d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0930p0219d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3pE005d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3pE004d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3362d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04CAp3008d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04CAp3006d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04CAp3005d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04CAp3004d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3375d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p817Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p311Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p3008d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p3004d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p0036d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v03F0p311Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0489pE027d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0489pE03Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0930p0215d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3304d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3pE019d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p3002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p3000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        bluetooth
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #####

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0

##### /etc/modules #####

lp

##### blacklists #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x1969:0x10a1 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC addr eth0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x168c:0x0032 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC addr wlan0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

[   11.512085] ath: phy0: Set parameters for CUS198
[   11.512089] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[   11.517786] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   11.518882] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[   11.518884] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   11.518886] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   11.518887] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[   12.204333] type=1400 audit(1408004306.051:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=457 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.204704] type=1400 audit(1408004306.051:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=455 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.204734] type=1400 audit(1408004306.055:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=456 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.204747] type=1400 audit(1408004306.055:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=457 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.371149] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   16.374803] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   17.419608] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC addr mladeks>
[   17.436511] wlan0: send auth to <MAC addr mladeks> (try 1/3)
[   17.439158] wlan0: authenticated
[   17.444982] wlan0: associate with <MAC addr mladeks> (try 1/3)
[   17.448448] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC addr mladeks> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[   17.448489] wlan0: associated
[   17.448499] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```